# Excel VBA code to copy and paste rows to new sheet failing

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I have the following VBA code that I am trying to use for excel to copy and paste rows that meet a certain criteria to a new sheet.

The code runs to the point of copying the first match in the sheet but fails pasting on the second sheet with the error

> Run-time error '14004': Application-defined or object-defined error

Can anyone help here?

```
Sub mileStone()
    Dim r As Long, pasteRowIndex As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long
    'lastRow = sht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

    lastRow = 24 ' need to include function to retrieve the last used row number 

    pasteRowIndex = 1

    For r = 11 To lastRow 'Loop through sheet1 and search for your criteria

        If Cells(r, Columns("E").Column).Value = "defect resolution" Then 'Found

            'Copy the current row
            Rows(r).Select
            Selection.Copy

            'Switch to the sheet where you want to paste it & paste
            Sheets("Sheet2").Select
            Rows(pasteRowIndex).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste

            'Next time you find a match, it will be pasted in a new row
            pasteRowIndex = pasteRowIndex + 1

            'Switch back to your table & continue to search for your criteria
            Sheets("Sheet1").Select
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

[image: Image as is]
[image: Image required]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be enough to get rid of all those Selects which usually cause problems and are rarely needed (just need to add sheet references). However, AutoFilter or Find would be quicker methods.

```
Sub mileStone()

Dim r As Long, pasteRowIndex As Long, v() As Long, i As Long

Dim lastRow As Long
'lastRow = sht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

lastRow = 13 '24 ' need to include function to retrieve the last used row number

pasteRowIndex = 1

With Sheets("Sheet1")
    For r = 11 To lastRow
        If .Cells(r, "E").Value Like "defect resolution*" Then
            If UBound(Split(.Cells(r, "E"), ",")) > 0 Then
                i = i + 1
                ReDim v(1 To i)
                v(i) = pasteRowIndex
            End If
            Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(r).Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Rows(pasteRowIndex)
            pasteRowIndex = pasteRowIndex + 1
        End If
    Next r
End With

With Sheets("Sheet2")
    If IsArray(v) Then
        .Columns(6).Insert shift:=xlToRight
        For i = LBound(v) To UBound(v)
            .Cells(v(i), "F") = Split(.Cells(v(i), "E"), ",")(1)
            .Cells(v(i), "E") = Split(.Cells(v(i), "E"), ",")(0)
        Next i
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution it worked just how I wanted. If I also have the data occurring in the same column as "defect resolution, 13/10/2017" and "defect resolution, 21/11/2018" for example, all as text format. Is there a way to rip the date on the new sheet, create a new column and have those text dates inserted in to the column as date formatted?

Comment: Not sure I follow. Do you mean the same row? "defect resolution" is in column E.

Comment: Sorry I meant the same fields, most fields would have the date, so after it is copied to a new sheet I need these actions to take the date, put in to a new column and format to be performed if possible

Comment: Sorry but still not sure what you are asking. Can you attach a screenshot or describe a specific example - where is the date, where should it go?

Comment: Hi I added two images to original question, the first is how the data appears on sheet1 and the second is how it should appear on sheet2. Please note that column F on the second sheet (containing the dates) would need to be a new column and short date formatted

Comment: Thanks, I see now. Do you have values in other columns which is why you want the new column F inserted? I might suggest you post this as a new question as it may require a different approach.

Comment: Yes need a new column on the second sheet, I presumed it would just be a new function that would fall outside of the loop. I'll post a new question, thanks for the help.

Comment: Don't worry, I'll amend the code above and let me know how it goes.

Comment: It is copying correct rows to sheet2 and is also creating new column, but the dates remain in column E the same as in Sheet1, and I get an error 400 pop-up box. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you know how to step through code using F8? Insert some breakpoints and find out where it breaks. It worked for me on a small test.

Comment: It is delivering the details to Sheet2 and inserting new column, just is not splitting date in to the new column. Unfortunately I cannot find the resolution in the code to assign output to the new column created in Sheet2

Comment: (1) Did you try what I suggested in my previous comment? Learning how to debug code is crucial. (2) Can you try with a sample as shown in your picture - that worked for me. Are you 100% sure it inserts a column?

Comment: (1) I did try to debug and I watched it step by step as it adds the rows to new sheet and then inserts the column. It is this line of code     .Cells(v(i), "E") = Split(.Cells(v(i), "E"), ",")(0)     that creates the 400 error. (2) 100% a new column is added jus the dates aren't added to the column

Comment: can you share your output?

Comment: It's literally the same as in your screenshots. What I don't understand is that if it inserts a column then it means it has found at least entry with defect resolution followed by a comma. When you look in the Locals Window what is in `v`?

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Copy_Filtered_Sections()

Dim Section As Long, NextRow As Long

For Section = 1 To 32

    NextRow = Sheets("Results").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'Next empty row

    Sheets("Function Test Procedure").Select

    Range("FTPSec" & Section).Columns("A:H").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
    Destination:=Sheets("Results").Range("A" & NextRow)

'        Range("FTPSec" & Section).Columns("G:H").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
'            Destination:=Sheets("Results").Range("N" & NextRow)

Next Section

End Sub
```

Acceptance Test Procedure Script

```
Sub Copy_ATP_Tables()

Dim SectionATP As Long, NextRow As Long

For SectionATP = 1 To 32

    NextRow = Sheets("Results").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'Next empty row

    Sheets("Acceptance Test Procedure").Select

    Range("ATPSec" & SectionATP).Columns("A:H").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
    Destination:=Sheets("Results").Range("A" & NextRow)

'           Range("FTPSec" & Section).Columns("G:H").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
'                Destination:=Sheets("Results").Range("N" & NextRow)

Next SectionATP


End Sub
```